# how to display a message if download is not successful

Tags: javascript, jsp, download

I am working on a webpage, I have a textbox and a download button. The user enters the file name in the textbox and clicks the download button to download the file.
This  is jsp code.

```
  out.println("<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" Content = \"2;URL=" + strUrl + "\">");
```

strUrl contains the path of the files.

The download works fine.
My problem is, if the file does not exists than I have to display a message in the webpage saying some thing like "File doesn't exists".

How am I going to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this javascript function:

```
function UrlExists(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```

This checks if the url returns a 404 error (file not found) or not.